# How I can multiply a=['raj' , 'rj' , 'reba'] with b=[1,2,2] (integers)to get the output as c =['raj' , 'rj' , 'rj' , 'reba' , 'reba']

Tags: python, list

How I can multiply

```
a = ['raj' , 'rj' , 'reba']
```

with

```
b = [1,2,2]  # integers
```

to get the output as

```
c = ['raj' , 'rj' , 'rj' , 'reba' , 'reba']
```

My current attempt is:

```
from itertools import chain
a = ['raj', 'rj','reba']
b = [1, 2, 2]
for i in range(len(a)):
   c.extend(list(a[i]*b[i]))
```

My current output:

`['r', 'a', 'j', 'r', 'j', 'r', 'j', 'r', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'b', 'a']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
a = ['Raj', 'Aby']
b = [1,2]
new_list = []
for i in range(len(a)):                # loop till list size
    temp_list = [a[i]] * b[i]          # ['Aby']*2 = ['Aby', 'Aby']
    new_list.extend(temp_list)         # extend() appends temp_list to new_list
print(new_list)                        # Thus ['Raj', 'Aby', 'Aby']
```

You can also combine `temp_list = [a[i]] * b[i]   new_list.extend(temp_list)` to `new_list.extend([a[i]] * b[i] )` . I wrote the other way for better clarity

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['raj', 'rj','reba']
b = [1, 2, 2]

c = []
for i,j in zip(a,b):
    c.extend([i]*j)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
['raj', 'rj', 'rj', 'reba', 'reba']
```

[`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) is python's built-in function which allows you to iterate over multiple lists using a single for loop.

[`list.extend`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_extend.asp) is function of datatype `list` which allows you to append element in a list

Comment: Could also use a listcomp to avoid in-place mutations: `[c for i, j in zip(a, b) for c in [i]*j]`. `itertools.repeat` could also be more efficient than the list product though I doubt it.

Comment: Yes? That's essentially what `list.extend` comes down to.

Comment: Thankyou it worked , if you can please write comment in this code, it would be a great learning for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `map` for that following way:

```
import itertools
a = ['raj', 'rj', 'reba']
b = [1, 2, 2]
m = map(lambda x,y:[x]*y, a, b)
lst = list(itertools.chain(*m))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['raj', 'rj', 'rj', 'reba', 'reba']
```

Note that this solution assumes that data are always correct i.e. `b` holds only `int`s and `len(a) == len(b)`. `map` as its `help` says

```
 |  Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
 |  each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.
```

In this case for each element of `a` I create 1-element `list` holding that element and multiply by corresponding value of `b`. Then I need to *flatten* it (I use `itertools.chain` for that) as without that I would get nested rather than flat structure.

Comment: Thankyou it worked , if you can please write comment in this code, it would be a great learning for me

Answer (score 1):

There's even an inline version, if you prefer it:

```
sum([[a[k]]*b[k] for k in range(len(a))], [])
```

Some comments:

- The inner list comprehension creates a list of lists, each of which contains the amounts of copies of `a[k]` specified by `b[k]`
- The sum then essentially reduces the list of lists to a flattened version by concatenating (or adding) all lists together. The second argument in the sum indicates where it starts from - an empty list (the argument is actualy needed, since the default is `0` and a list cannot be added to an Integer).